# Is there anything similar to Laravel Events/Queues in ASP.NET using redis as cache/queue storage?

Tags: asp.net, laravel

Is there anything similar to Laravel Events/Queues in ASP.NET using redis as cache/queue storage? I'm look to implement asynchronous based queued event-driven architecture where I can publish my object asynchronously which flows through to redis gets queued and then something picks up it and processes it. I'm looking to know what that something should be in an asp.net mvc/web api type projects and how to build/incorporate it?

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on best practices for asking questions that will get you best answers.

Good luck.

Comment: I found the best tool to do this - Hangfire.io